# How can I store data from MySQL into html using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is something I need help on.

Im going to allow a user from my database to "share" a record which gets sent from the database into a solid html file.

So I'm looking at ways to create a html file from data in a database which is passed through php and stored in a location on the server. with no interaction from the user at all other than pressing 'share'. They would be sent the url to look at it upon success.

I'm looking for any functions or tuts on how to best make a html file from php. any help is appreciated. I think I may be looking into this too much, and the answer may be staring me in the face

Comment: Make an html file should refer to dynamic web page which is controlled by the php script, or everytime the 'share' is accessed to create a static html file?

Comment: yes, sorry. i couldnt find the words - static html file dynamically created

Comment: Start here: "what do you mean by pressing 'share'?" What kind of button is that? Where does it come from?

Comment: Please share some of the code you have already written or tell us what you are having problems with. Do you have a server up and running? MySQL? PHP set up with mysql extension?

Comment: @arkascha simply a button which starts a function

Comment: @jasonnathan im having trouble creating a html file from php. I cant really find the best way to do it

Comment: So - a HTML form element that calls a PHP function, PHP functions that read from databases, that write to HTML files... I'd say you're almost where you want to be. How do you want to piece them together?

Comment: Why does it need to create an actual physical HTML file?

Comment: Seems simple as hell. You have the database. So connect to it via PHP, do the needed query, fetch the records, open a file (like `fopen`), send the data to it, write on the server (like `fwrite`) with the respective name

Comment: @deceze because usually the record can only be seen by the end user when logged in.

Comment: @Ricki ...? I still don't see what this has to do with a physical HTML file. Are you looking for an *authentication and authorization system*?

Comment: @RoyalBg yes.. I see now my stress levels are too high. If you put that in an answer i will close this debacle

Comment: Aha... "simply a button". Ok, if you say so... I wondered if that button is inside a html page or on the desktop or inside some applications windows or what...

Comment: @arkascha yes.. yes. I realise I'm being a bit daft. not my best moment in life, I must say

Comment: Ah, don't worry. Though I would like to mention: one should enjoy _all_ moments life offers!

Comment: @Ricki, normally you don't "create" a HTML file from php. PHP files contain some code that eventually outputs HTML to the browser. So if you have a file called `index.php` and you run it, the file is processed and HTML is sent to the browser so you can see the results. Is this what you are trying to achieve? Or do you want to create an HTML file like `index.html` ?

Comment: well i will certainly learn from this. simply diving into something without mapping my actions is irresponsible

Comment: @jasonnathan the answer below explains what i mean. I dont think today is the day to make new projects happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it got clear, you want static html files, created dynamically via PHP and written on the server.

The steps you need to follow are clear too:

- You need the database and as you said you have it
- You need to connect to it via PHP
- Then do the respective queries
- Fetch the data from them
- Use it in the HTML
- Open a file
- Send the used data to it
- Write the file with the relevant name

The querying should start after the button `share` is clicked (you can track this via isset() function)

Comment: thank you for opening my eyes. I'm a bit stupid right now